# Hash::check() return false in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm just starting with laravel 5, I'm doing a simple login function to check if email and password passed by user matches with the email and password stored in the database. I've been reading the documentation ([https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing[1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/hashing)) but `Hash::check($content['password'], $user->{'password'})` returns false always. My code looks like this.

When I create a new user I hash the password like that:

```
$content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

$user -> password = Hash::make($content['email']);
```

And my login function looks like that:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $content = json_decode($request -> getContent(), true);

    $user = DB::table('users')->where('email', $content['email'])->first();


    if (Hash::check($content['password'], $user->{'password'}))
    {
       // Redirect to dashboard
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried changing `if (Hash::check($content['password'], $user->{'password'}))` to `if (Hash::check($content['password'], $user->password))`?

Comment: I get the same result...

Comment: @IcarKwon i hope my answer will fix this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are hashing the email instead of password while creating the user. change the code from

```
$user->password = Hash::make($content['email']);
```

To

```
$user->password = Hash::make($content['password']);
```

Comment: Oh my God... what a shame. I spend my last 3 hours... hahaha
Thanks @Jinu P C

Answer (score 0):

i came up with same issue. check database users table, password field. make the size of the field to 60 or more. this fixed mine.

Comment: My password field is a VARCHAR 255 length :(. Thanks anyways!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The facade Hash just will encrypt your data:

```
Hash::make('123456');
```

is the same that:

```
$password = bcrypt('123456');
```

to login a user you need to use AuthController functions:

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => 'test@test.com' , 'password' => Hash::make('password')]);
```

it's a example.

If you're receiving a request, you can add this method to login:

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email'   =>  $request->email, 'password'    =>  $request->password , 'active'    =>  1])){
        flash()->success('Successfully logged in!');
        return redirect('/');
}
```

the attempt function will hash your password field and will compare with database data.